# Create new jQuery object by index (array)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array `$myElements` with some elements with in. When I show them in the console, it looks like this:

[image]

Now I'm trying to create a new `jQuery` `object` for the element with `index 1` within `$myElements`, and than I would like to use `animate()` to make an animation for it.

I tried it in two ways:

```
const currentElement = $(this.$myElements[1]);
```

and

```
const currentElement = $(`.${this.$myElements[1].className}`);
```

Than I tried an example animation like this:

```
currentElement.animate({
    transform: 'scale(1.75)'
}, 1000);
```

My animation is not working. I'm not sure if the way I tried to create a new jQuery object is wrong or the animation?

Comment: `$(this.$myElements).eq(1);`

Comment: @bambam I tried it, the animation is still not working... maybe there is an error?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]